# Average of Receiver operating characteristic(ROC)

Tags: r, mean, roc

I have 10 ROC and AUC from 10 folds cross-validation

how can I get the mean of them?
I used `library(ROSE)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions here. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49568224/edit) your post and provide (1) sample data, (2) an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and (3) your expected output.

Comment: I think this question should be asked on stats.stackexchange...

Comment: If you are posing a coding question, you should have resolved any methodological issues first. Coders need an answer to the "how to do X?" question. I for one have never seen a description of an "average ROC`.